# How to make folders appear in search results?

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-search

When I use the file search (<kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>) in Windows 8.1, and use a name of a folder which is indexed, all the files in that folder appear. However, in Windows 7, the start menu search also included the folder itself, and clicking on it would open the folder in windows explorer. Is there a way to imitate this behavior in 8.1? Also, the 'everywhere' option seems to include only a subset of the results from 'files', shouldn't it be an aggregate of all the different types of results?